# which is Executes first and how should i know ? (Apex trigger and Workflow)

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow

If i wrote one trigger (after insert) on ACCOUNT, and at the same time i also created one workflow rule for ACCOUNT.

So, my question is which will execute first ? (Trigger or Workflow)

And How should i know that trigger execute first or workflow rule fire ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers (both before and after) fire before workflow rules.  Workflow rules could cause the after triggers to fire again.

Use this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) as a reference to know the full order of execution.

Comment: No problem, glad to help  :)